# cant display image from json object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I am trying to display data from my JSON objects, my object is as follows in 2 images

[image]

[image]

within data, I have `c_name`, `max_slots` and an array `slots` in that array I have `base_image`

I can not get the base image array to display in my HTML.

This is my current printout in HTML

[image]

here is my JavaScript

```
      $scope.GetData = function () {
        $http({
            url: "http://www.ccuktech.co.uk/ccuploader/campaigns/getCampaign",
            method: "POST",
            date: {},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }).then(function (data) {
            // success
            console.log('you have received the data ');
            console.log(data);
            $scope.responseData = data.data;
        }, function (response) {
            // failed
            console.log('failed getting campaigns goo back to log in page.');
            console.log(response);
        });
     };

     $scope.GetData();
```

and HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="data in responseData">
  <h2>name</h2>:
  {{data.c_name}}

  <h2>max slots</h2>:
  {{data.max_slots}}

  <h2>image</h2>:
  {{data.base_image}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant just display an image within the div tag, use **`<img>`** instead of it

```
<div ng-repeat="data in responseData">
    <h2>name</h2>:
    {{data.c_name}}
    <h2>max slots</h2>:
    {{data.max_slots}}
    <h2>image</h2>:
     <img ng-src="{{data.base_image}}"></img>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `base_image` is inside an inner array, you have to loop that array inside your `ng-repeat` of `responseData`

```
<div ng-repeat="data in responseData">
  <h2>name</h2>:
  {{data.c_name}}

  <h2>max slots</h2>:
  {{data.max_slots}}

  <h2>image</h2>:
  <div ng-repeat="slot in slots">
    <img src={slot.base_image} />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Trying now bro, were using jade here so just converting then will accept answer again. thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{data.base_image}}
```

won't be accessible because it is inside nested `slots` array so in order to refernce `base_image` you have to iterate through slots as well. Try something like given here :

[ng repeat nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542768/ng-repeat-in-nested-array-in-angularjs)